# navigation area mongodb + Express.js + ejs

Tags: mongodb, express, ejs

I have a project in Express.js with ESJ and mongodb that consist of several pages (not more than 3). All the pages are structured the same:

1. navigation area (which has to remain the same in all pages)
2. main area and
3. footer zone (which has to be the same in all pages).

The information in the navigation area has to be brought from a mongodb collection (let’s say “categories”), so the navigation is the result of a query of “categories” collection. Also, on the same page, in the main area has to appear the result of a query of another collection from the same db (let’s call it “products”).

My question is: how it is possible to keep the same navigation are, with the last selection, and change the info in the main are while going from one page to another, all in the same page?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking with "all in the same page" means no reload between two pages.

There are several ways to obtain this and it depends of the weight of your data and your preferences. I assume in my answer that you know Express.JS, EJS and MongoDB.

You can use AJAX but you will need a little bit of client-side javascript code (to ease that, you can use a js-framework like jQuery or similar). In this case, I advise you to use EJS in the browser and to perform asynchronous JSON calls to Express.js.

Otherwise, if your main area data is light enough, you can have a one-page scroll site. Your navigation area will be maid of links using html anchor. You can use EJS on the server-side. There will be only one route in Express.js for all your website.